# impossible NSInvalidArgumentException - attempt to insert nil object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsmutablearray

I'm getting NSInvalidArgumentException
`*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil` exception through Crashlytcs on line 1148 in my code, showing you the 1147-1149 lines of my code :

```
if(snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs) {
    [self.usedStickers addObject:snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs];//1148 line
}
```

`self.usedStickers`  is `NSMutableArray`

How is this possible ? (I know there's possibility that crashlitycs is showing wrong line, but that is unlikely because this crash appeared in 9.20 version of the app, and in 9.24 version it's still in 1148 line).

UPD: stickerInfoForAnalitycs is a NSString * property, without getter/setter override. declared as `@property (nonatomic) NSString * stickerInfoForAnalitycs;`

Comment: `snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs` is `nil`.

Comment: Message clearly says that `snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs` is nil. Make sure that there is a always a value

Comment: Ok, I just read the whole snippet, and while I am not an objC programmer, `if(snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs) {` test should make sure that is not nil... right?

Comment: @luk2302 but if(snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs) is for checking that case

Comment: What type of object is `snapshot` and what is `snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs`?

Comment: @DonMag it's a NSString *, without getter setter override

Comment: @passingnil - ok, maybe try it this way: `NSString *s = [snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs copy]; if (s) { ... }` That will also allow you to put a breakpoint there to inspect what's going on.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear: if `s` is not nil, the addObject line should be `[self.usedStickers addObject:s];`

Comment: @DonMag i've debugged and stickerInfoForAnalitycs was always not nil

Comment: @passingnil - hmmm... are you getting the error when debugging, even if the object to add is not nil? Just to rule a possible "mis-reported error", maybe add a check to make sure `self.usedStickers` is not the nil object?

Comment: @passingnil What is the threading model in your app?   How often does `stickerInfoForAnalytics` change and from how many threads?

Answer (score 1):

According to code snippet you've provided, you are ensuring that `snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs` is not `nil` before adding it into an `NSMutableArray`.

Error message `-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]` clearly indicates that `self.usedStickers` is not `nil` and in fact is an instance of `__NSArrayM`, which is a privte subclass of `NSMutableArray` class cluster. That is going right as expected.

So, I can come up with the most likely scenario in which issue still may happen - the other thread modifies `snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs` value right after it was tested in `if` statement, but before it was inserted into the array.

So, I would suggest checking that other threads do not modify `stickerInfoForAnalytics` value. Running your code with enabled thread sanitizer may help. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/thread_sanitizer/enabling_the_thread_sanitizer for details. Note that thread sanitizer is an extremely good tool, but it still can't detect every possible issue. So, you'll still need to read your code and find all places where `stickerInfoForAnalitycs` value changed.

Another possibility is, for example, - a custom implementation for `stickerInfoForAnalitycs` method may return correct value on first access, but `nil` on second. I consider this option as unlikely.

Comment: this issue appeared 192K times and 100K+ users affected by this, do you think that in all that cases before executing the [self.usedStickers addObject:snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs] line, the snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs  is being modified from other thread  ?

Comment: @passingnil, then it looks weird to me. I would not expect this root cause in your case then, but it still worth to double-check. Make sure that `stickerInfoForAnalitycs` implementation is correct if you have a custom getter for this property, as per my last suggestion.

Comment: stickerInfoForAnalitycs - is a simple NSString * property without getter/setter override. @property (nonatomic) NSString *stickerInfoForAnalitycs; is the declaration of that propery

Comment: Then the only possibility I see is the threading issue. @nithinbhaktha suggestion may help, but as I mentioned in comment to his answer, you'll need to perform similar changes in other code that is using usedStickers. If that's the case - my suggestion with thread analyzer will help to detect the issue too.

Comment: thanks for help, but actually fabric was showing wrong line.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing properties, it's always best practice to assign a value to a local variable to ensure the property is not mutated between the time it is checked and the time it is used. Alternatively, you can use `@synchronized` blocks to ensure all accesses of a property are mutually exclusive.

Fundamentally, your assumption that it's impossible for the value to be `nil` is wrong since you're getting the value two different times.

```
NSString *stickerInfoForAnalitycs = snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs;
if (stickerInfoForAnalitycs != nil) {
    [self.usedStickers addObject:stickerInfoForAnalitycs];//1148 line
}
```

With this code, it truly will be impossible to get the `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

Answer (score -4):

You might as well try this :

```
if(snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs) {
     @synchronized(self.usedStickers) {
        [self.usedStickers addObject:snapshot.stickerInfoForAnalitycs];//1148 line 
     }
}
```

Comment: Might have sense, but you'll also need to implement synchronized access to `self.usedStickers` in other code that modifies or queries contents of this array

Comment: The use of `usedStickers` isn't the source of the bug and this code does not protect access to anything.